# CopyFromScreen in timer not refreshing image

Tags: vb.net

I'm setting up an application to take captures from the screen but ran into a problem where the image refuses to refresh.

I have found that the image refreshes when the form is out of view and another window is selected. I also tried running the program in debug mode and found that it merges the old image with the new, so I tried to clear the image first and the results were the same.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    gfx.CopyFromScreen(New Point(Location.X + PictureBox1.Location.X + 8, Location.Y + PictureBox1.Location.Y + 31), New Point(0, 0), pic.Size)
    PictureBox1.Image = pic
End Sub
```

I was expecting the image to refresh properly when adding the refresh or invalidate to the picture box but instead it only refreshes when it is out of view.

Comment: You should be using `PointToScreen` to convert from client coordinates to screen coordinates.  For instance, `PictureBox1.PointToScreen(Point.Empty)` will give you the screen coordinates of the top-left corner of `PictureBox1`.  If it's a direct child of the form, so will `Me.PointToScreen(PictureBox1.Location)`.

Comment: I am using this only on a small portion of the screen not the entire screen. so I don't need the coordinates of the screen.

Comment: How do you declare that `Graphics` object mate? I mean _gfx_.

Comment: `Dim pic As Bitmap = New Bitmap(270, 100)`                                                  `Dim gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(pic)`

Comment: The first argument to `CopyFromScreen` is literally the screen coordinates of the top-left corner of the rectangle you want to copy so how can you say that you don't need to know screen coordinates?

Comment: I see. Here's your answer: [Graphics.CopyFromScreen Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen?view=netframework-4.8). Good luck.

Comment: How does it make sense that the `PictureBox` is displaying a copy of itself?  Please edit your question and provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I am not using the top left corner of the screen. The top left for me is somewhere in the middle.

Comment: All I need is to find out why the image is refreshing only when out of view.

Answer (score -1):

I found it out on my own the solution is as follows:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    gfx.CopyFromScreen(New Point(Location.X + PictureBox1.Location.X + 8, Location.Y + PictureBox1.Location.Y + 31), New Point(0, 0), pic.Size)
    PictureBox1.Image = pic
    PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You probably meant:  `PictureBox1.Image?.Dispose() PictureBox1.Image = pic`. Which causes a Refresh() of the control (plus disposes of the disposable object your created).